# read content of spreadsheet from google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Well, I think this question should be pretty straight forward. I am using Google drive SDK to manage my google drive files.

I want to export the content of a particular spreadsheet. 
I could find the fileId, exportLinks collection. The Authorization is not a problem.

There are two issues remained to be solved.

First, after I use drive_service._http.request(exportlinks[type]) to export the sreadsheet, I cannot recognize the returned content. How should I convert it to something I would read.

PS: The three types of exporting that spreadsheet supports are all fine for me. And I am using Python.

Second, if my spreadsheet have multiple sheets. How could I decide which one I want to export?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exported type will be the one you request. If you are requesting CSV, then it will be CSV. (I am not sure this is what you are asking, so if it isn't please expand.

Multiple sheets are a problem for certain file types like CSV. You can select the sheet by using the `gid` parameter. This is currently unsupported, so please do not be upset if it doesn't work well:

```
&gid=1
```

There is more information on the old Documents List API docs, but as I say this is unsupported behaviour: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_spreadsheets

For a complete solution, please export to a format that supports multiple sheets.

Comment: thanks for answer! After some research and experiences, I realize that it is impossible to read the content of a file unless you export it first, right? By the way, google drive spreadsheet export method only support three options(which doesn't include csv), though I certainly can force it to export as .csv file. However, as you mentioned, it fails with multiple sheets. For exporting, after export it with .xlsx format, I have to save it as a .xlsx file to read it, right? I cannot simply read from  my memory without saving, right?

Comment: By the way, sometime the sheet name are incomplete after you export it. Is this a bug or you have the length limit on sheet name? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just found out that when you export spread sheet from google drive, the sheet name length is limited to 31. That why some of my sheet names are incomplete. Is there any solutions?